# Getting Null Pointer on Reference to TabHost (Android)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-tabhost

This is something that's been bugging me for the past day now. So I keep getting a null pointer reference to mTabHost, a variable in onCreate(). Here's the pertinent code:

From my main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    instance = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

    // Initializing ViewPager and TabHost objects:
    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.viewpager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this,getSupportFragmentManager());

}
```

And here is second_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <fragment android:name="com.yolostudios.dots.main.login.LoginFragment"
            android:id="@+id/login_fragment"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="8" >

            <include
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:focusable="true"
                layout="@layout/createspotbutton" />

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <!-- Loading header of this UI which is coded separately -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" >

            <include
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="20dp"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

The actual exception is thrown when I run 
    mTabHost.setup(this,getSupportFragmentManager()) as mTabHost is null.

Something strange I have noticed is that even the sample FragmentTabs given in Support4Demos does not work for me. I am pretty sure that this tells me something is wrong with my android-support-v4.jar or my environment but I have tried re-downloading the jar and re-compiling but still nothing works: despite compiling fine, both my project and the sample project fail at runtime. As for other possible environment issues, I am not sure what they could be.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Andrew.

Comment: Remove `android.` from `android.R.id.tabhost`, I know Eclipse wants it there.

Comment: Please see my response to Tarsem's answer

Comment: Is your class extending `FragmentActivity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    instance = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this,getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Initializing ViewPager and TabHost objects:
    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.viewpager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);


}
```

Comment: No, I don't believe that works because if you'll notice in second_activity.xml, the id that is given to the FragmentTabHost is \@android:id/tabhost, and so R.id.tabhost is not found as a valid R.id. I tried changing \@android:id/tabhost to a simple \@+id/tabhost and then referencing it with R.id.tabhost, but that resulted in the same nullpointerexception.

Comment: I do not have that import. I am importing the R class from my own package.

Comment: I tried your updated answer, and now mTabHost is returning with what it should! However, mViewPager is now returning null. Do you have any idea why findViewById is not working as it should in my code?

Comment: are you extending SherlockFragmentActivity ?

Comment: No I'm not, just FragmentActivity. I'm going to see if I can run with your idea some more. If I get it working because of it I'll mark your response with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you change it to :

```
setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

// Initializing ViewPager and TabHost objects:
mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
mViewPager.setId(R.id.viewpager);
setContentView(mViewPager);
mTabHost.setup(this,getSupportFragmentManager());
```

}

Since you're calling setContentView with a different layout before finding the object that's within the first layout file?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this may be the case. But keep this **below message** in mind when using `Fragment/FragmentHost/FragmentActivity`

remember use `Activity` if you are using android.app.Fragment; use `FragmentActivity` if you are using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Never attach a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` or `FragmentHost` to a `android.app.Activity`, as this will cause an `Exception` to be thrown.